# Within for-loop, Input file not reading new values into variables

Tags: c++, file-io

I am currently having trouble in the for-loop reading new values into variables.  It works perfectly fine for the vertices, edges and start variables, but it will only work for the first time around for the from_, to_, weight_ and dir variables.  Each time the for-loop iterates after that, it still uses the second line (0 1 4 false).  I'm ashamed to have to post for something so meager, but I can't for the life of me figure out what's going on.  I've included the input file as well as the function that is used from the implementation file, which uses an object of a struct, Edge, which is put into a list object in a vector.  Please let me know if I should post more, although I think the problem simply has to do with how I'm using the file I/o.

```
#include "graph.h" 
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <vector> 
#include <list> 
#include <limits> 
#include <fstream> 

int main() 
{ 
    std::ifstream infile; 
    infile.open("graph.txt"); 
    int vertices, edges, start; 
    infile >> vertices >> edges >> start; 
    Graph graph(vertices); 
    int from_, to_; 
    double weight_; 
    bool dir; 
    std::cout << "Constructing graph" << std::endl; 
    int i = edges; 
    for (int i=0;i<edges;i++) 
    { 
        infile >> from_ >> to_ >> weight_ >> dir; 
        graph.addEdge(from_, to_, weight_, dir); 
    } 


    infile.close(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

The input file (graph.txt):

```
6 8 2 
0 1 4 false 
0 2 7.5 false 
1 3 2 false 
1 4 5 false 
2 3 3.1 false 
2 5 6.9 false 
3 4 1 false 
4 5 3 false
```

The function in the implementation file:

```
void Graph::addEdge(int from, int to, double weight, bool isDir) 
{ 
    std::cout<< "Representing edge " << from << "," << to << " weight " 
            << weight << std::endl; 
    Edge e1(from,to,weight); 
    if (adjacent.size() < std::max(from, to) + 1) 
        adjacent.resize(std::max(from,to) +1); 
    adjacent[from].push_back(e1); 
    std::cout << "Edge added" <<std::endl; 
    if (isDir == false) 
    { 
        Edge e2(to,from,weight); 
        adjacent[to].push_back(e2); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `false` and `true` for Boolean like that. There is no string representation of it, so trying to parse a Boolean as a string fails.

Use:

```
std::string dir;
```

And then after:

```
graph.addEdge(from_, to_, weight_, dir != "false");
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading a `bool` normally expects to find `1` or `0`.
(If you had checked whether reading succeeded, you would have noticed that it doesn't.)

You can use the [`std::boolalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha) I/O manipulator to make the stream look for the character sequences `true` and `false` instead.

Example (it works for output streams, too):

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::istringstream in("true false");
    bool value = false;
    in >> std::boolalpha;
    while (in >> value)
    {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << value << "\n";
    }
}
```